# Spock unit test, groovy leftshift assignment is throwing a SpockExecutionException: Data provider has no data

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, junit, spock

I'm writing a spock unit test and I get the following error thrown when I try to supply a data provider dynamically using groovy collect

```
SpockExecutionException: Data provider has no data
```

Here is the simplest case I can provide that throws the error:

```
import spock.lang.Shared
import spock.lang.Specification

class SampleTest extends Specification {

    @Shared
    def someArray

    void setup() {
        someArray = ['a','b','c']
    }

    def "ensure that 'Data provider has no data' is not thrown"() {

        expect:
        columnA == columnB

        where:
        [columnA, columnB] << someArray.collect { value -> [value, value] }
    }
}
```

The groovy code seems to work. Here's my test on the groovy console:

```
def someArray = ['a','b','c']
def test = someArray.collect { value -> [value, value] }
println test

[[a, a], [b, b], [c, c]]
```

What am I misunderstanding?

I'm using:

- **groovy** version *2.2.1*
- **spock** version *0.7-groovy-2.0*
- **junit** version *4.12*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `setupSpec()` instead of `setup()` to access the `@Shared` variable the way you want to, as indicated in [`@Shared` documentation](http://spockframework.github.io/spock/javadoc/1.1-SNAPSHOT/spock/lang/Shared.html). Alternatively, you can also initialize the shared variable during it's declaration.

```
import spock.lang.*

class SampleTest extends Specification {

    @Shared someArray

    // This is similar to just using
    // @Shared someArray = ['a','b','c']
    // Use above instead of setupSpec() if required
    // setupSpec() is invoked before any test case is invoked
    void setupSpec() {
        someArray = ['a','b','c']
    }

    def "ensure that 'Data provider has no data' is not thrown"() {
        expect:
        columnA == columnB

        where:
        [columnA, columnB] << someArray.collect { [it, it] }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @dmahapatro. I really appreciate the prompt response. I added a link to the documentation for the Shared annotation as well, the answer was right there, if only I had read it. :)

Comment: Thanks & Not a problem. Spock (and Groovy in general) never ceases to amuse. :)